# Show date in jqplot tooltip

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jqplot

I am using jquery jqplot(bar chart) with ruby on rails application. I am sending date as Apr, 2012 and amount in dollars to chart. On bar mouseover tooltip is showing date as index i.e
[1, $200], [2,$300] instead of date(Apr,2013). How can i replace this index with date?? where
date is on x-axis and amount is on y-axis.
Here is my highlighter code:

```
highlighter:
  show: true
  showMarker: false
  formatString: '<table class="jqplot-highlighter">
                 <tr><td><b>%s</b></td><td><b>%s</b></td>
                 </tr></table>'
```

Comment: date present on which axis?

Comment: Date is present on x-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you added this JS?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"></script>
```

And try this:

```
highlighter: {
    tooltipAxes: 'y',
    yvalues: 2,
    formatString: '<table class="jqplot-highlighter">
                     <tr><td><b>%b</b></td><td><b>,%Y</b></td>
                     </tr></table>'
}
```

[More details.](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html)

Comment: made a change. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it. Its not working properly. In tooltip %Y is displaying as it is. Date is not properly rendering.

Comment: please put `tooltipAxes: 'y'` and `yvalues: 2` and try `%s`